# Изменение поля объекта xts

Tags: r

Всем привет! Начал изучать R и возникла проблема. 
Есть некий объект(содержащий дату и цены) типа xts вида:

```
            Settle
2015-02-13  14.88
2015-02-17  15.14
2015-02-18  15.09
2015-02-19  14.68
2015-02-20  14.39
2015-02-23  14.31
2015-02-24  14.17
2015-02-25  13.79
2015-02-26  14.08
2015-02-27  13.93
```

Во второй строке хочу изменить год. Т.е. должно получиться:

```
            Settle
2015-02-13  14.88
2014-02-17  15.14
2015-02-18  15.09
2015-02-19  14.68
2015-02-20  14.39
2015-02-23  14.31
2015-02-24  14.17
2015-02-25  13.79
2015-02-26  14.08
2015-02-27  13.93
```

Помогите решить этот вопрос. Кучу материала перерыл, ничего не нашел.

```
> str(R)
An ‘xts’ object on 2015-02-13/2015-02-27 containing:
  Data: num [1:10, 1] 14.9 15.1 15.1 14.7 14.4 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr "Settle"
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Во временном ряде вы хотите изменить не просто год, а значение индекса.
Пример ниже демонстрирует возможности изменения индекса временного ряда

Имеем файл csv

[image: csv file]

Подключаем библиотеки

```
    library(xts)
    library(dplyr)
```

1-ый вариант. Замена значения индекса во временном ряде.
создаем временной ряд из дата фрэйма

```
    fl.df <- "D:\\-DtF\\q723601\\df.txt"
    df <- read.csv(fl.df, header = FALSE, sep = " ")
    my.ts <- xts(df[, -1], order.by=as.POSIXct(df$V1))
```

Получаем результат:

```
                [,1]
    2015-02-13 14.88
    2015-02-17 15.14
    2015-02-18 15.09
    2015-02-19 14.68
    2015-02-20 14.39
    2015-02-23 14.31
    2015-02-24 14.17
    2015-02-25 13.79
    2015-02-26 14.08
    2015-02-27 13.93
```

Проверяем результат

```
    class(my.ts)
    > [1] "xts" "zoo"
```

Интересующее значение индекса

```
    index(my.ts)[2]
    > [1] "2015-02-17 +07"
```

Для работы с индексом временной серии используем **index()** предварительно преобразовав значение года

```
    index(my.ts)[2] <- as.POSIXct("2014-01-01")
```

Получаем ошибку:

```
    > Error in `index<-.xts`(`*tmp*`, value = c(1423760400, 1388505600, 1424192400,  : 
    new index needs to be sorted


    index(my.ts)[1] <- as.POSIXct("2014-01-01")
    my.ts
```

Получаем результат:

```
               [,1]
   2014-01-01 14.88
   2015-02-17 15.14
   2015-02-18 15.09
   2015-02-19 14.68
   2015-02-20 14.39
   2015-02-23 14.31
   2015-02-24 14.17
   2015-02-25 13.79
   2015-02-26 14.08
   2015-02-27 13.93
```

Как видим замена значения индекса во временном ряде возможна только в случае соблюдения условий **Предыдущее значение индекса** < **Значение** < **Следующее значение индекса**

2-ой вариант. Замена значения через преобразование в data frame
создаем временной ряд

```
    fl.df <- "D:\\-DtF\\q723601\\df.txt"
    df <- read.csv(fl.df, header = FALSE, sep = " ")
    my.ts <- xts(df[, -1], order.by=as.POSIXct(df$V1))
    my.ts

                [,1]
    2015-02-13 14.88
    2015-02-17 15.14
    2015-02-18 15.09
    2015-02-19 14.68
    2015-02-20 14.39
    2015-02-23 14.31
    2015-02-24 14.17
    2015-02-25 13.79
    2015-02-26 14.08
    2015-02-27 13.93
```

временную серию преобразуем в дата фрэйм

```
    df.frm.ts <- data.frame(dt=as.Date(index(my.ts)), Val = (my.ts[,1]))
    df.frm.ts

                       dt   Val
    2015-02-13 2015-02-12 14.88
    2015-02-17 2015-02-16 15.14
    2015-02-18 2015-02-17 15.09
    2015-02-19 2015-02-18 14.68
    2015-02-20 2015-02-19 14.39
    2015-02-23 2015-02-22 14.31
    2015-02-24 2015-02-23 14.17
    2015-02-25 2015-02-24 13.79
    2015-02-26 2015-02-25 14.08
    2015-02-27 2015-02-26 13.93
```

при необходимости индекс в data frame можно заменить на целочисленные значения

```
    rownames(df.frm.ts) <- c(1:nrow(df.frm.ts))
```

производим замену 2-го элемента в дата фрэйме (df.frm.ts)

```
    df.frm.ts[2,1] <- as.POSIXct("2014-02-16") 
    df.frm.ts

               dt   Val
    1  2015-02-12 14.88
    2  2014-02-15 15.14
    3  2015-02-17 15.09
    4  2015-02-18 14.68
    5  2015-02-19 14.39
    6  2015-02-22 14.31
    7  2015-02-23 14.17
    8  2015-02-24 13.79
    9  2015-02-25 14.08
    10 2015-02-26 13.93
```

преобразуем в time series

```
    my.ts2 <- xts(df.frm.ts[, -1], order.by=as.POSIXct(df.frm.ts$dt))
    my.ts2

                 [,1]
    2014-02-15 08:00:00 15.14
    2015-02-12 07:00:00 14.88
    2015-02-17 07:00:00 15.09
    2015-02-18 07:00:00 14.68
    2015-02-19 07:00:00 14.39
    2015-02-22 07:00:00 14.31
    2015-02-23 07:00:00 14.17
    2015-02-24 07:00:00 13.79
    2015-02-25 07:00:00 14.08
    2015-02-26 07:00:00 13.93
```

Как видим значения при образовании во временный ряд будет отсортировано по значению даты